# TYPO3 8.7 TCA Configuration of inline Element

Tags: typo3-8.x

In TYPO3 8.7 I want to create an inline element where the child elements never collapse automatically when the backend user opens or closes any child element in the backend.

According to the docu this should be achieved with the following option:

> expandSingle (boolean) 
>   "Show only one child-record expanded each time.
>   If a collapsed record is clicked, the currently open one collapses and
>   the clicked one expands."

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/singlehtml/Index.html#document-ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline

So I set up my TCA configuration like this:

```
'rm_project_gallery' => [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:gallery/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:gallery_element.sheet.inline.label',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'inline',
        'appearance' => [
            'expandSingle' => false,
        ],
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 999,
        'foreign_table' => 'tx__gallery_element_gallery',
        'foreign_field' => 'content_element',
    ],
],
```

But it does not lead to the intended behaviour:

When I expand one element the others collapse.

Is this a bug? Or did I miss something?

Comment: have you verified this configuration? is it active in your BE? have you tried 'expandSingle' => 0` ?

Comment: yes, yes and yes, same result

Comment: in the heading you wrote 8.7, the text begins with 8.6. which is the typo? looking for an existing bug I found the [reverse bug](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/67691) maybe it was fixed wrong. you might open a new bug and look in the old patch.

Comment: sorry, 8.6 was wrong. I edited the text. I use 8.7.

Thank you for your research. I wanted to ask here first, before I open a bug ticket.

Comment: SO is no bug validation. try slack or open a bug-ticket. A bug-ticket always will be verified (and maybe rejected if not repeatable).

Comment: sorry, if i used SO wrong.

My intention was to make sure that my configuration is correct.